# Maven : OSGI, bundles and multi-modules projects

Tags: maven-2, osgi, dependencies

I'm currently developing an OSGi based application (using Equinox) by trying to mavenize a web tutorial I've found on OSGi+Equinox. In this project, there are bundles depending on other bundles (quote-service depends on quote).
The compile phase does succeed, but the package phase does not. Maven complains the following :

```
[INFO] [bundle:bundle]
[ERROR] Error building bundle de.vogella.osgi:quote-service:bundle:0.0.1 : Unresolved references to [de.vogella.osgi.quote] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]: [de/vogella/osgi/quoteservice/Activator.class, de/vogella/osgi/quoteservice/QuoteService.class]
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
```

I do understand the problem, but do not see how to make it work.
This is the quote's pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>osgi-first-app</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.vogella.osgi</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.vogella.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>quote</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Quote Bundle</name>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <_include>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</_include>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and the quote's bundle manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Quote Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.vogella.osgi.quote
Bundle-Activator: de.vogella.osgi.quote.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Export-Package: de.vogella.osgi.quote
```

Then the quote-service's pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>osgi-first-app</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.vogella.osgi</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.vogella.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>quote</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.vogella.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>quote-service</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Quote Service Bundle</name>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <_include>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</_include>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And finally the quote-service's manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Quoteservice Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.vogella.osgi.quoteservice
Bundle-Activator: de.vogella.osgi.quoteservice.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0", \
 de.vogella.osgi.quote;version="0.0.1"
```

Is there something wrong ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 12):

The answer is quite simple : I removed the already defined manifest, and used bnd entries in the bundle plugin instructions. That works !

Comment: I'm sure this Q&A will be very useful to me some day, so I voted it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Tycho](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/tycho-040-roadmap/) is designed to handle these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool called auto-builder: http://code.google.com/p/auto-builder.  It introspects PDE-based projects and generates Ant build files; it supports transitive closure over dependencies and all that jazz.

I posted a write-up: http://empty-set.net/?p=9.  I wrote it because the Maven tools I played with, when integrated with PDE, didn’t “just work.”  Basically, I wanted to do coding in PDE and have a Hudson-based CI without any fuss in between.

Generating Ant files is nice because it gives you all the benefits of a declarative build tool, but it leaves you with a procedural description of what it is doing.

I am looking for more PDE-based projects to test it on.  There are a couple RFC-0112 Bundle repositories around, and I have some code for downloading dependencies.  If anyone is interested, then I could integrate dependencies download with auto-builder.